# Use locationlistener in RecyclerView.OnScrollListener

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, locationlistener

I need to get user location and send request by this location to server. I have a recyclerview for showing the data of server. To update location I use this code in onStart in the main activity and want to get location in idle state of recyclerview. Now I don't know how can I implement the location listener.

Maint Activity:

```
if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,  new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);
    }else{
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(locationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10000, 0, locationListener);

    }
```

and:

```
public abstract class StoryPaginationScrollListener extends RecyclerView.OnScrollListener{

LinearLayoutManager layoutManager;
LocationListener locationListener;
Context context;


public StoryPaginationScrollListener(LinearLayoutManager layoutManager, LocationListener locationListener, Context context) {
    this.layoutManager = layoutManager;
    this.locationListener = locationListener;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
    super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);

    if(newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){

    }
}

@Override
public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
    super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

    int visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
    int totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
    int firstVisibleItemPosition = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();





    if (!isLoading() && !isLastPage()) {
        }
        if ((visibleItemCount + firstVisibleItemPosition) >= totalItemCount && firstVisibleItemPosition >= 0) {
            loadMoreItems();
        }
    }
}



protected abstract void loadMoreItems();

public abstract int getTotalPageCount();

public abstract boolean isLastPage();

public abstract boolean isLoading();


}
```

In need a location in this condition: `if(newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE)` and use this location in loadMoreItems().

Comment: Probably you should make your `Activity` implement the `LocationListener` interface i.e. have the `onLocationChanged()` method and have a member variable that always stores the latest received location. You could then read this variable in `StoryPaginationScrollListener` assuming it has access to the `Activity`. Android Studio will guide in implementing the interface if that's a problem. And prepare to wait for the location. Especially the first GPS based location may take a while to appear. Network (cell tower) based is fast, but not so accurate.

Comment: Even I use locationlistener in main activity can use in `StoryPaginationScrollListener` ?

Comment: No, it needs to in either one. And of course you may know better which is the right place in you app. but as getting the location is an asynchronous operation, I thought it might make sense to have the listener in the Activity and keep the latest location stored, so you can just read it from the Activity when you need it and can start loading more content for your RecyclerView right away.

Answer (score 0):

try to implement `LocationListener`
like this

```
class MyActivity extends Activity implements LocationsListener{
    public Location location

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        this.location = location
    }

    public void someLogic(){
        new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener(){
        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int newState) {
            super.onScrollStateChanged(recyclerView, newState);
            if(newState == SCROLL_STATE_IDLE){
                if(location != null){
                    //write your code here
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScrolled(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);
        }
    };
    }
```